# New to android. Not sure why the app is not running

Tags: java, android, eclipse, runtime-error

I encountered the below error. But I am not sure what is going on. Can some kind soul please explain to me. Heres the logcart error;

**Log-cart:**

```
 09-18 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 09-18 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337):
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
 ComponentInfo{com.example.mdp11/com.example.mdp11.MainActivity}:
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
 "com.example.mdp11.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
 "/data/app/com.example.mdp11-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.mdp11-2,
 /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] 09-18 20:55:52.292:
 E/AndroidRuntime(19337):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
 09-18 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
 09-18 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 09-18
 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
 09-18 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337):   at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-18
 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337):     at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-18 20:55:52.292:
 E/AndroidRuntime(19337):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 09-18
 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-18
 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 09-18 20:55:52.292:
 E/AndroidRuntime(19337):   at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
 09-18 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337):   at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 09-18
 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337):     at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-18 20:55:52.292:
 E/AndroidRuntime(19337): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
 Didn't find class "com.example.mdp11.MainActivity" on path:
 DexPathList[[zip file
 "/data/app/com.example.mdp11-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.mdp11-2,
 /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] 09-18 20:55:52.292:
 E/AndroidRuntime(19337):   at
 dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
 09-18 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337):   at
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 09-18
 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337):     at
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 09-18
 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337):     at
 android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
 09-18 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
 09-18 20:55:52.292: E/AndroidRuntime(19337):   ... 11 more
```

Comment: looks like you're missing a class called 'MainActivity'?

Comment: Its `ClassNotFoundException` , have you renamed package ?

Comment: Yes. I changed the name of my MainActivity class. What should I do to correct it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to declare it on your AndroidManifest xml file

add this

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="appname" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting the code will probably help. The part you want to look at is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
 "com.example.mdp11.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
"/data/app/com.example.mdp11-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/data/app-lib/com.example.mdp11-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] 09-18
```

So you are trying to start an activity called MainActivity, but it can't be found under the path.

Comment: This answer should be a comment posted under the OP's question.

Comment: What is OP's question?

Comment: OP's quesion is your question, the original question.